# How to convert an unity3d game app crash log backtrace to code location

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

```
***** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/volantis/flounder:7.1.1/N9F27M/4333998:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 23136, tid: 23160, name: UnityMain  >>> com.kumora.emblem <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
    r0 c0d0d570  r1 00000000  r2 00000024  r3 00000038
    r4 c0d0d578  r5 00000038  r6 de77d141  r7 c837fc78
    r8 00000000  r9 ce4e7694  sl 00000024  fp df1c5c70
    ip dea4fab0  sp d0f75a18  lr de80ec47  pc de77d148  cpsr 600b0030
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00914148  /vendor/lib/libglcore.so
    #01 pc 009a5c45  /vendor/lib/libglcore.so
    #02 pc 009a5fd9  /vendor/lib/libglcore.so
    #03 pc 0079ef39  /vendor/lib/libglcore.so
    #04 pc 005130b0  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #05 pc 00264054  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #06 pc 002631c0  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #07 pc 005b7eec  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #08 pc 005b7fa8  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #09 pc 0019ac44  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #10 pc 0045ef4c  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #11 pc 00199ef0  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #12 pc 0019b6e4  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #13 pc 0019c690  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #14 pc 001a34c8  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #15 pc 00125d90  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #16 pc 00128364  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #17 pc 00149794  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #18 pc 002e7b34  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #19 pc 002e941c  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #20 pc 00540a68  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #21 pc 00543248  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
    #22 pc 0020e629  /data/app/com.kumora.emblem-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x1ec000)
```

I am using [this method](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000292166-Symbolicate-Android-crash) to convert the address to code location but the result seems no right. Is there any better way to find the crash code location in my file or unity native code?

Comment: do not post your log as an image

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, please go throug [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question. include the code you want to ask about not an external link.

Comment: @Benjamin sorry i changed

Comment: There is no code left after build. You can't trace the line where it happens coz that line is no longer a text but a binary. You'd have to debug with proper printing to know where and why.

Comment: @MohammadKanan thanks i will read it